# Create Mac menu bar application with html/js/css?

Tags: javascript, macos, air

I'd like to build a simple app for mac that has an icon that sits in the upper right menu bar leveraging html/css/js (I don't know any objective-C)...

Is there a way to do this? My first thought is to use something like Adobe Air but I'm not sure if it can do this...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the repository where you can download the necessary dependencies to build a menubar application with HTML, CSS, and JS. It's built on top of Electron if you're familiar with that framework.

https://github.com/maxogden/menubar

This works on OS X, and purportedly works on Windows and Linux, although I cannot verify the Windows and Linux claims.

Clone the repository. `npm install` from the repo's root.

Need a fast example?

`cd` into the `/example` directory; `npm install` there also. Then run `npm run build` followed by `npm start`. Check your menubar to examine the newly generated application ("Hello World"). Use this as a skeleton to getting started quickly.

If you experience any difficulties, be sure that you have `electron-prebuilt` installed. You can either use `npm install -g electron-prebuilt` if you're into installing globals. Otherwise, run `npm install electron-prebuilt` and symlink to it using:

```
$ ln -s ./node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron <PATH-TO-SYMLINKS>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to program it in objective-c. I'm not really sure about Adobe Air's ability to access the systems menu bar, but it's unlikely you'll be able to do it through that and using HTML/CSS/JS are web based languages.

Do a simple search, like "Objective-c menu bar app". You'll find a lot of tutorials that will get you started. I started programing in obj-c with menu bar apps :)

You might find this helpful though if you're trying to work closer with web languages: http://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2013/07/statusbar-with-nodobjc.html